# How to downgrade Docker on Mac to 1.12.x or connect to 1.12 hosts from 1.13 in Mac?

Tags: macos, docker

I recently upgraded my Docker on Mac to last 1.13 version. Fail. I can't now execute docker commands to my docker hosts running on OpenSUSE Linux or Fedora Atomic. They only support 1.12 (I get an error stating "different client versions")
How can I make my Mac support 1.12 version docker hosts or, if that's not possible, just downgrade my MacOS Docker to last version of 1.12? In docker.com I just see the link to install last version, 1.13 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

One of the features of 1.13 was supposed to be a [client that automatically downgraded to older API's](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/27745), so I'm surprised to hear this issue.

To revert to an older api, simply run:

```
export DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.24
```

replacing the API number with whatever you need. With that variable set, the client will connect with the older API to any server you want.